# Delphi 10 Seattle & DB SQlite основы - Ввод и Ввывод информации из БД

Tags: delphi, sqlite

Столкнулся с тем что нужно сохранять данные в базе данных sqlite, научился лишь создавать файл *.db пробую к нему подключиться и сделать запись выдаёт ошибку

> [dcc32 Error]  E2010 Incompatible types: 'TFDCustomConnection' and 'TSQLConnection'

А вот код:

```
FDConnection1:=TFDConnection.Create(self);
FDConnection1.DriverName:='Sqlite';
FDConnection1.Params.Add('Database=D:\db.db');
FDConnection1.Params.Add('FailIfMissing=False');
FDConnection1.DriverName := 'SQLite';
FDConnection1.Connected := True;

// link Local SQL to SQLite connection
FDLocalSQL1.Connection := FDConnection1;
FDLocalSQL1.Active := True;

// execute SELECT query on above datasets
FDQuery1.Connection := FDConnection1;
FDQuery1.SQL.Text:='insert into test (test_id, test_text) VALUES (10,''1'')';
FDQuery1.Active := True;
```

Ошибка идёт на эту строку `FDLocalSQL1.Connection := FDConnection1;` а если ее удалить то на вот эту `FDQuery1.Connection := FDConnection1;`
Почему оно не хочет конектиться? Пример брал отсюда `docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Local_SQL_(FireDAC)`
Если кто нибудь знает напишите простой пример как правильно нужно подключаться, записывать/считывать данные, отключаться, мне всего нужно записать, порядковый_номер и длинный_текст

Приведите пожалуйста рабочий пример на TFDConnection или на TSQLConnection, на TSQLConnection у меня получилось создать файл и записать в него данные, но прочитать его никак не получается и подскажите стоит ли вообще использовать SQlite для хранения и обработки данных под 10 Гбайт?

Comment: Запутался в своём коде... Текст сообщения набрал часов 10 назад, но не отправил потому что были найдены интересные материалы которые не дали положительный результат решения моей задачи

Comment: `FDLocalSQL1` объект какого типа?

Comment: Не знаю... Я первый день пытаюсь разобраться с подключением к sqlite, вполне возможно что мне и не нужен `FDLocalSQL1`

Comment: Как это не знаете? Программа ваша? Как объявлена эта переменная и где создается этот объект?

Comment: 99% что Вы говорите неправду. Т.к приведенный код не может давать такую ошибку

Comment: `FDLocalSQL1: TFDLocalSQL;`  - компонент находится на форме, я запутался в количестве и названиях ошибок, сижу часов 15, мучаю гугл своими запросами, может стоит пойти уже поспать, извините за не корректно заданный вопрос, мне нужно всего лишь создать бд, с таблицей и двумя полями (порядковый_номер, много_текста), на словах легко...

Comment: Приводите конкретный код и конкретный текст ошибки и Вам помогут

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете конструкцию `FDLocalSQL1.Active := True`, то должны вначале использовать `FDLocalSQL1.Active :=false`.  Я предпочитаю другой подход, через `Clear` и в зависимости от того, ждёте ли вы выборку или нет, - `ExecSQL` или `Open`.

Пример работы с таблицей SQLIte через VCL-компоненты:

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    DBServer: TSQLConnection;
    SQLQuery1: TSQLQuery;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
<...>
   procedure InitBase(SQLConn: TSQLConnection; FileName: string); // мне так проще, я часто использую TSQLConnection в связке с TSQLQuery вне форм, но в этом случае создавать объекты надо вручную
  end;

procedure TForm2.InitBase(SQLConn: TSQLConnection; FileName: string);
begin
  SQLConn.ConnectionName := 'SQLITECONNECTION';
  SQLConn.DriverName:='Sqlite';
  SQLConn.LoginPrompt:= false;
  SQLConn.Params.Values['Host']:='localhost'; // это не обязательно, дань привычке
  SQLConn.Params.Values['FailIfMissing']:='False';
  SQLConn.Params.Values['ColumnMetaDataSupported']:='False'; // несмотря на то, что для Windows должно бы быть TRUE, у меня почему-то не работает, False решает все проблемы
  SQLConn.Params.Values['Database']:=FileName;
  SQLConn.Open;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 s:string;
 count:integer;
begin
  InitBase(DBServer, 'P:\SQLLite_DBs\new_base1.sdb'); // подключим файл базы
  SQLQuery1.SQLConnection := DBServer;
  s:= 'CREATE table `temp_pos` (`chr` varchar(16) NOT NULL, `pos` bigint(20) NOT NULL, `count` int(11) NOT NULL); ';
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Add(s);
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL; // вы создаете таблицу, поэтому ExecSQL
  s:= 'INSERT into `temp_pos`(`chr`, `pos`, `count`) values ("1", 123, 2);';
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Add(s);
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL;
  s:='SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `temp_pos`';
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Add(s);
  SQLQuery1.Open; // вы получаете данные, поэтому Open
  if SQLQuery1.RecordCount>0 then
     begin
       SQLQuery1.FindFirst;
       count:=SQLQuery1.Fields.Fields[0].AsInteger;
     end;

<...>
  // в конце не забываем

  DBServer.Close;

end;
```

Про 10 гигабайт данных ничего не могу сказать: даже полгигабайта таблицы не достигали. В скорости SQLite уступает MySQL, особенно если использовать бездумно, но зато "всё свое ношу с собой" :)

Comment: ExecSQL, Open - это же, фактически, более низкоуровневые функции обращения к SQlite3.dll, чем другие? Вы их из-за скорости выбираете?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Хм... Нет :) Хотя я и знаю, что, в случае SQLite это, фактически, прямой враппер к функциям DLL, я просто привык писать так :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Спасибо добрый человек, заработало :) сколько инфы в инете перекопал всё не то или в основном не работает

Comment: @ViktorTomilov снова какая то беда, из проекта `А` скопировал весь код в новый проект `В`, рядом с программой положил ту же самую `sqlite3.dll` запускаю и получаю ошибку `unknown driver Sqlite`, переношу в папку `В` программу из проекта `А` запускаю всё ок, если удалить `sqlite3.dll` проект `А` выдаёт ошибку `sqlite3.dll  not found`, а проект `В` так же пишет `unknown driver Sqlite`, два часа копирую код из проекта в другой проект... в чём проблема? ((

Comment: @lib скопировали код, но не скопировали компоненты на форме?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov + компоненты тоже все скопировал, уже весь uses который у проекта А перенёс в проект В, такое ощущение что он ищет драйвер совсем не в `sqlite3.dll` потому что если удалить `sqlite3.dll` он не выдаёт ошибку о том что либа не найдена...

Comment: @lib Такое бывает, когда вы скопировали только код и компоненты, но не свойства компонентов, заданные ваи в design-time. поэтому я и спрашиваю, вы копировали проект полностью, включая DFM?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Разобрался... упустил в uses добавить Data.DbxSqlite... и ошибки не было от дельфи. Спасибо за ответ)